# ButtonsSet widget disappears in collapsible CardSection on Android in Gmail apps script add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

There is a problem with visibility of ButtonsSet widget in collapsible CardSection on Android.

I have the menu section with buttons in it. It works perfectly on ios and web.
However the buttons disappear on android.
Tried to run different scenarios:

1. To set a section header.
2. To add an extra widget (textParagraph).
3. Set section's `collapsible` property to `false`.

No changes in #1 and #2. ButtonsSet disappears in collapsible sections.
#3 works normally - buttons are shown.
But I would like to have collapsible section in this place.